# Where toString fails to work?

Tags: javascript, tostring

```
function dTree() {
    return {
        init : function(data) {
            this.data = data;
        },
        node : function(i){
            return '' + i;
        }
    }
};
dTree.prototype.toString = function() {
    var str = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++)
    {
        str += this.node(this.data[i]);
    };
    return str;
}
dTree1 = new dTree();
dTree1.init([1,2,3]);
alert(dTree1+'')
```

I'm expecting it to output `123`

How to do it the right way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not how you make constructors. Constructors don't return anything, they manipulate the `this` object:

```
function dTree() {
    this.init = function(data) {
        this.data = data;
    };
    this.node = function(i){
        return '' + i;
    };
}
```

You could also stick the definition of `toString` into the constructor as well, unless you're doing something special with it:

```
function dTree() {
    this.init = function(data) {
        this.data = data;
    };
    this.node = function(i) {
        return '' + i;
    };
    this.toString = function() {
        var str = '';
        for(var i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++)
        {
            str += this.node(this.data[i]);
        };
        return str;
    };
}
```

Comment: Why not move the other two functions to the prototype as well, instead of moving `toString` to the constructor? Doesn't declaring functions in the constructor make a copy for each instance or something in that direction?

Comment: @Bart: I was just demonstrating how constructors work in JavaScript. In practice, sure, you would probably want to put methods on the `prototype` object.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a plain new object from your constructor, the `this` object inside your constructor is not used at all, and that object is the one that has the right prototype object assigned.

```
function dTree() {
  this.init = function(data) {
    this.data = data;
  };
  this.node = function(i){
    return '' + i;
  };
}

dTree.prototype.toString = function() {
  var str = '';
  for(var i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++)    {
      str += this.node(this.data[i]);
  };
  return str;
};

dTree1 = new dTree();
dTree1.init([1,2,3]);
alert(dTree1 + '');
```